# tf.metrics.x is not supported when eager execution is enabled (TensorFlow 2.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I am trying to use metrics from `tf.metrics` in Tensorflow 2.0 and it seems like all of them are not supported when eager execution is enabled (for example [see](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py#L359)). Is there an example of how to make some of them to work when eager execution is enabled or what is the strategy of using them?